# How to convert Big Number to decimal

Tags: reactjs, typescript, bignumber.js

I'm trying to convert a big number to decimal but when ever I call to string it always returns 0

```
import { BigNumber } from 'ethers';

const destDenominator = BigNumber.from((10 ** 18).toString());
const minReceived = BigNumber.from('4560000000000000').div(destDenominator);
```

When ever I call toString it always returns 0.  How do I get a decimal value from when dividing two big ints?

Comment: A division operation involving two [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) values always results in another `BigInt` (which has no fractional information).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Percent.

```
import { Percent } from '@uniswap/sdk-core'

const destDenominator = BigNumber.from((10 ** 18).toString());
const minReceived = BigNumber.from('4560000000000000');
return new Percent(minReceived, destDenominator)
```